# Deploy app that works on background on WAS

Tags: java-ee-6, websphere-8

I made an app that I'm deploying as EAR on WAS 8.5. This app works as an app that constantly checks on a DataQueue and transfer whatever message it finds to an MQ. Since I've been testing it, I realized that if I start it, it remains starting the application indefinitely (since it's an endless loop that checks on the queue). Even without the loop, the read() function of the dataqueue reads indefinitely until it finds a message, what also makes the starting of the app to don't end.

Reflecting on it, I realize that an EAR (with WARs, JARs, etc) it's an app that expects a request (if not all, most of the time). So if it's an endless loop, it won't end the starting of the EAR.

Maybe there's another way to deploy this application on WAS. Is there a way to deploy the app so it will be like a background process that does everything I previously mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to this:

1. Use MDBs and ensure that you receive the message is a message listener thread. This will ensure that threading is completely taken care by WAS.
2. Here is an article about using threads in WAS: http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/2010/09/developing-multi-threaded-application.html .

Comment: Ok, because I can't use theads (project constraint), MDB it is, I think. Now, I'm using a web project on a ServletContextListener to deploy the EJB Jar (there's a method in the EJB that it's executed at the start of the EAR automatically). If I want to deploy the MDB, how can I make the method to automatically start at the start of the EAR? (assuming that the whole web project thing is not right)